# Function that return other function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

everybody!
I have trouble with "Functions that return functions", I don't think I understand really well.
The problem that I need to solve is: I have to write a function `counter` that return other function `counter2`, and each time I call the function, this must return a counter that increase 1 each time.

I have this code:

```
function counter() {
var count = 0;
  function counter2(){
  count++;
  }
return counter2();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: just `return counter2` instead of `return counter2()`. Remember, adding `()` to the end of a function name calls that function

Comment: http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.html

Comment: less weird version of the above is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

A function is just an object.

```
function counter2(){
  count++;
}
```

You can access the object by typing `counter2`. E.g. check out what happens when you run the code: `console.log(counter2)`. This will print the function object to the console.

Be aware that `counter2()` is the syntax used to call a function. This will invoke the functions code and return its return value. At the end `()` is just an operator that can be used on the function object.

A perfect guide can be found on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp